# Concatenate results set within a query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i have a look up table that was written a long time ago, and it saved large text in multiple rows with the following structure:

```
eventID
Text
LineNum
```

whenever i want to pull it all out i "`select text from tblEvent where eventID = 4 order by LineNum`"

however now i'm trying to join this table to the main table and pull all of the text from the Event table.

```
select m.*,STUFF((select ',' + e.TEXT from tblEvent e where CURRENTFLAG = 'Y' and e.eventID= g.eventIDfor XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as 'EVENT' from tblMain m
```

in the above, the text get's cut off half way through (even if it's all stored in 1 row in the lookup table)

what am i doing wrong here? how to get get it all out?

Comment: can you add schema for your tables and some sample data so we can attempt to recreate the issue please

Comment: Is it getting cut of in SSMS results panel? If you are what output are you using (Result to Text or Result to Grid)?

Comment: i'm doing "export to excel" in SSMS, the text is definitely not going over the Excel cell limit, but is still getting cut when i do the STUFF funciton.

Comment: if the problem is while exporting to excel, then you can divide your text column into x parts (x=column width/255). like substring(text,1,255),substring(text,256,510)...so that they can fit according to the excel cell width.

Comment: Are you viewing the text in SSMS?  If so, check column can output a maximum of 65535 characters.